# Android customize first child of grid view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I want a grid view in which first child alone should be there in first row with different layout design and remaining childs can be similar in their designs. How can I achieve this? Please refer to the screen shot to get the idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really possible but it is possible to fake it. The trick is to split the bitmap in half and show each half as separate images. See [Bigger image for first item of the gridview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111917/bigger-image-for-first-item-of-the-gridview-android/11112313#11112313) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is one nasty way to do it. 
Add an empty entry to the list at position 1
And then in getView:

if position is 0 set layout width of that item to be 2x normal width.

if position is 1 (or make some kind of flag for that item) inflate empty layout like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```