# Android layout - custom grid like layout

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am trying to find solution how to display images in 2 columns grid with first row need to be one element with two columns width.

[Android customize first child of grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237500/android-customize-first-child-of-grid-view)

I found this. but I hope there is some better solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `FrameLayout`. This kind of `layout` allow you to put more than one `Layout` or `XML` item above each other.

I recommend for you to use the `FrameLayout` as a parent `layout`. Inside it put two `GridViews` the first one will represent the first wide element. The second `GridView` will be the normal small elements.

Put into your first `GridView` with your specific `XML` properties (Double wider than the others) only one item. Put into your first `GridView` with your specific `XML` properties the rest of items.

When you are handling the actions or the filling of the second `GridView` neglect the first two positions (Position 0 and 1) then act normal for the other.

Here is a good [example](http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/android-framelayout-example/) of the `FrameLayout` usage. And here is a simple [example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) of the `GridView` usage. I hope it helps

Comment: Perfect! But this answer might be tough for people that don't have experience with Android.